# how to run tomcat 7 version in windows 7

Tags: servlets

I have downloaded apache-tomcat-7. My JDK version is jdk1.8.

How do I configure CATALINA_HOME as an environment variable, and also please tell how to run tomcat server under Windows 7.
i set all path like

```
  CATALINIA_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin;.;
  CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\lib\servlet.api
  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;.;
```

in system variables

even though i m getting set CATALINA_PATH Environment variable not defined properly.. pls give the solution

Answer (score 0):

1. download the Apache tomcat zip version and extract it some where (Let's assume on "D:/" drive)
2. right click on "My Computer" and select "Properties--> Advanced System Settings-->Advance [tab] ".
3. click on "Environment Variables" button.
4. on "user variables" , click on "New" button and add below values:
   CATALINA_HOME = D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.53
   JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\
5. Under "System Variables", select the existing "Path" variable and click on "Edit".
6. Under "variable value", go to the end of the values and enter below:
   D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin;
7. Save all settings you made.
8. Open up a new command line and enter " echo %CATALINA_HOME% " and see whether you have set the path correctly.

that's all... hope this would help you..

Comment: No its not working.. but when i m entering echo %CATALINA_HOME% i m  getting path correctly

Comment: What is not working...? can you please be more informative...? say what you have done so far and what is failing more clearly so we could be able to help you...

Comment: what you have asked is "How do I configure CATALINA_HOME as an environment variable" and I have told you how to set it up.. now what is your issue?